# Generalised homology of a split fibration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

Let $E, X$ be path-connected and suppose I have a fibration $p\colon E\to X$ which admits a section $s$. 
For a generalised homology theory $\mathcal{E}_\ast$, there is  a splitting $\mathcal{E}_\ast (E)\cong \mathcal{E}_\ast(X)\oplus R_\ast$ induced by $p$ and $s$.

Choosing a basepoint $x\colon \ast \to X$, we have a homotopy fibre sequence
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} F & \to & E \\ \downarrow &  & \downarrow \\ \ast & \to & X \end{array}
$$
which implies a map $\psi\colon \mathcal{E}_\ast(F) \to \mathcal{E}_\ast(X)\oplus R_\ast$.
Commutativity of the diagram implies that projecting $\psi$ to the first factor results in the zero map.

**Question:** is the map $\mathcal{E}_\ast (F)\to R_\ast$ an isomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the following (split) homotopy fiber sequence
$$S^1\to S^1\times S^1\to S^1$$
Then, by a standard argument, we have 
$$\Sigma(S^1\times S^1)=S^2\vee S^3\vee S^2$$
so for every spectrum $E$
$$E_*(S^1\times S^1)=E_*(S^1)\oplus E_*(S^2)\oplus E_*(S^1)$$
In particular the sequence
$$E_*(S^1)\to E_*(S^1\times S^1)\to E_*(S^1)$$
is not exact (the first map is the inclusion of the first summand and the second one is the projection onto the third summand).

Comment: Thanks! It's good to have such a clear counterexample. A follow-up question: in this example the homology of the homotopy fibre _injects_ into the homology of the total space. Is this something that occurs generally for split fibrations? (for arbitrary fibrations it is, of course, false)

Comment: @VBM I don't think it is true, but no counterexample immediately springs to mind (maybe the sphere bundle obtained by fiberwise 1-point compactifying some vector bundle can do the trick). You should try to consider the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence for ordinary homology, that should clarify the relationship between the homology of the total space and the homology of the fiber.

Comment: As far as ordinary homology with field coefficients goes, the splitting implies the collapse of Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence at $E_2$, so the homology of the fiber injects to that of the total space.